# mediaelement.js: remove and restore player

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement

I have here a video element:

```
<video id="playerFrame" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-bottom:10px; position:relative; display:none;"></video>
```

and two javascript functions. One show the element and start to play the movie:

```
document.getElementById('playerFrame').style.display = '';
player.setSrc(sources);
player.load();
player.play();
```

the other one hide the element and remove the player:

```
document.getElementById('playerFrame').style.display = 'none';
player.pause();
player.remove();
```

The first time, when the function is called, it works: the player shows and start to play. When the function for hide and remove get calls, the player get deleted. That's fine, but when I call the function for playing again, it shows the player, but you only listen the sound and the control panel is gray.

Is there a way, to totally clear the player and build them new?

Comment: The only way I found now is, to add a div around the video element and hide this one with `display:none` and set the player only on **pause()**, not on **remove()**.